# pass multiple inputs sql query shiny

Tags: sql, shiny

I have an sql query that works well with 1 input parameter 
e.g.

```
mydf1=dbGetQuery(con2, paste0("select month from incoming where to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP(vessel_servertimestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'MON') in  '",input$dataset1,"' 
group by  month "))
```

How do  construct an sql query to pass multiple input parameters? Below is the selectInput..

```
output$dataset1 =renderUI({
      selectInput("dataset1", "Choose month:", 
                  choices  = as.list(c("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC")),
                  multiple = TRUE)
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change sql part with input$dataset to

```
in (", paste0("'", input$dataset1, "'", collapse = ","), ") group_by month"
```